# $X_nY_n$ converges to zero

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that $X_n$ converges in probability to zero and $Y_n$ converges in probability to zero as $n$ goes to infinity. Prove that $X_nY_n$ converges in probability to zero.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: For any $\epsilon > 0$,

$|X_nY_n| > \epsilon$ implies that $|X_n| \geq \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$ or $|Y_n| \geq \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$ (why?). Thus, $$\{|X_nY_n| > \epsilon\} \subseteq \left\{|X_n| \geq \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}\right\}\cup\left\{|Y_n| \geq \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}\right\}$$

Comment: Ok , Thank’s alot